# How does the parameter flex-grow work in an fxFlex directive?

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I'm trying to use the angular [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout), but I have a problem with the directive **fxFlex** and in particular with the parameter `flex-grow`.

The doc says :

> flex-grow: defines how much a flexbox item should grow (proportional to the others) if there's space available. The flex-grow value overrides the width.

So I thought that with the following code, the second `div` should have been twice as big as the second one and should have filled the empty space :

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxFlex="2 1 30%">[flex="2 1 30%"]</div>
    <div fxFlex="1 1 40%">[flex="1 1 40%"]</div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work as I expected and I can't find out in which conditions the argument `flex-grow` is used ?

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/L02xpT6Xs13jfac8FAlv?p=preview) is the plunker I worked with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd highly recommend checking out [this link](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API) for more examples on what to expect from the 'grow shrink initial' in a flex environment.

I [forked your plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/po3B31aurPulrJnQVkGO?p=preview) for some examples on how to use the grow-shrink initial.

Examples include:

**1st box 20% width, and the other two boxes splitting the remaining space in thirds**

*2nd box is half the size of 3rd*

```
  <div fxFlex="1 1 20%"></div>
  <div fxFlex="1 1 auto"></div>
  <div fxFlex="2 1 auto"></div>
```

**split entire space in tenths**

*1st 8/10th, 2nd & 3rd 1/10th*

```
  <div fxFlex="8 1 auto"></div>
  <div fxFlex="1 0 auto"></div>
  <div fxFlex="1 0 auto"></div>
```

**split space in thirds**

*first box twice the size of second*

```
  <div fxFlex="2 0 auto"></div>
  <div fxFlex="1 0 auto"></div>
```

I know the documentation says otherwise, but I've been working with this quite a bit and found:

- If you set an initial size the flex-layout will not grow or shrink
- the grow/shrink is relative to the other boxes with `auto` initial size

Flex-Layout sets the actual flex to "1 1 1e-9" when you set an initial value, which is why the grow shrink has no effect.